# Mostrar un video fragmentado

Tags: python, opencv

estoy haciendo correspondencias entre puntos característicos con python entre dos videos *.avi, pero para acelerar el trabajo me gustaría que solo lo hiciera en uno de cada 5 frames hasta el final del video, es decir, reducir un video de 300 a 60 frames, ¿Como podría realizar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Para reducir un video cada 5 cuadros podrías utilizar opencv (librería para visión computacional). Probé con lo siguiente y me resultó (aunque al reducir los cuadros por segundo quedó un video que se ve cortado); tal vez te podría servir:

```
import cv2
import os

path = 'C:/Users/Ejemplo' #acá debes dejar la ruta de la carpeta donde se encuentra el video original

os.chdir(path) #comando que permite cambiar directorio base en tu sesión de python
video_name = 'demo.avi' #definir nombre completo del archivo de video de origen
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
ret, frame = cap.read() #primera captura del cuadro en la variable frame
fps_video=cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) #frames por segundo original del video video_name
height,width = frame.shape[:2]
out = cv2.VideoWriter('demo_output.avi',fourcc, int(fps_video/5), (width,height))

# =============================================================================
# out:Objeto/video de salida con parámetros de frames por segundo, ancho y alto del video. 
# En este caso definí el entero 
# de la división (cuadros por segundo original/5); puedes setear este valor 
# como sea más conveniente para ti
# =============================================================================

count = 1

while ret:

    if count==1 or count%5==0: #Si el cuadro corresponde al primero o cada 5 cuadros, entonces guarda el cuadro/frame en el objeto 'out'

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=1.0, fy=1.0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        print("saving frame: {}".format(count))
        out.write(frame)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    else: #caso contrario: pasar al siguiente cuadro
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    count = count+1

cap.release()
out.release()
```